# Why is my ModelChoiceField showing three forms instead of two and why is it not reading my choices?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

[image]
First of all, I have two model forms fused into one form and they are supposed to show topic name and question type, but for some reason, three forms are showing up and the first one is not showing choices where the second one is showing up two times, and I don't want the second one which is the one with the choices showing up in it because my CSS are not applied on it.

- Choices are not showing up.
- Three forms instead of two.

This is my `model.py`

```
from django.db import models
from home.choices import *

# Create your models here.

class Topic(models.Model):
    topic_name = models.IntegerField(
                    choices = question_topic_name_choices, default = 1)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.topic_name

class Image (models.Model):
    image_file = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.image_file

class Question(models.Model):
    questions_type = models. IntegerField(
                    choices = questions_type_choices, default = 1)
    question_topic = models.ForeignKey(    'Topic',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    blank=True,
                                    null=True)
    question_description = models.TextField()
    question_answer = models.ForeignKey(    'Answer',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    blank=True,
                                    null=True)
    question_image = models.ForeignKey(    'Image',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    blank=True,
                                    null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.question_description

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_description = models.TextField()
    answer_image = models.ForeignKey(    'Image',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    blank=True,
                                    null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.answer_description
```

This is my `forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from betterforms.multiform import MultiModelForm
from .models import Topic, Image, Question, Answer
from .choices import questions_type_choices, question_topic_name_choices

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    topic_name      =   forms.ModelChoiceField(
                    queryset = Topic.objects.all(),
                    widget = forms.Select(
                    choices=(question_topic_name_choices),
                    attrs = {'class': 'home-select-one'}
                    ))
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['topic_name',]

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    question_type =   forms.ModelChoiceField(
                    queryset = Topic.objects.all(),
                    widget = forms.Select(
                    choices=(questions_type_choices),
                    attrs = {'class': 'home-select-two'}
                    ))
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['questions_type',]
class QuizMultiForm(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes    =   {
                'topics':TopicForm,
                'questions':QuestionForm
    }
    def save(self, commit=True):
        objects = super(QuizMultiForm, self).save(commit=False)

        if commit:
            topic_name = objects['topic_name']
            topic_name.save()
            question_type = objects['question_type']
            question_type.topic_name = topic_name
            question_type.save()
        return objects
```

This is my `views.py`

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
    from django.views.generic import CreateView
    from home.models import Topic, Image, Question, Answer
    from home.forms import QuizMultiForm



    def QuizView(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = QuizMultiForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                pass
        else:
            form = QuizMultiForm()
        return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form})
```

This is the `choices.py`

```
question_topic_name_choices = (
    (1, ("Topic #1: Measurements and Uncertainties")),
    (2, ("Topic #2: Mechanics")),
    (3, ("Topic #3: Thermal Physics")),
    (4, ("Topic #4: Waves")),
    (5, ("Topic #5: Electricity and Magnetism")),
    (6, ("Topic #6: Circular Motion and Gravitation")),
    (7, ("Topic #7: Atomic, Nuclear and Particle Physics")),
    (8, ("Topic #8: Energy Production")),
    (9, ("Topic #9: Wave Phenomena (HL Only)")),
    (10, ("Topic #10: Fields (HL Only)")),
    (11, ("Topic #11: Electromagnetic Induction (HL Only)")),
    (12, ("Topic #12: Quantum and Nuclear Physics (HL Only)")),
    (13, ("Option A: Relativity")),
    (14, ("Option B: Engineering Physics")),
    (15, ("Option C: Imaging")),
    (16, ("Option D: Astrophysics"))
        )

questions_type_choices = (
    (1, ("Multiple Choice Questions")),
    (2, ("Problem Solving Questions")))
```

This is the template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
  {% block content %}
        <form  method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
          <button type="submit" id="home-Physics-time-button">It is Physics Time</button>
        </form>
    {% endblock content %}
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Why are you setting the `choices` attribute on your `ModelChoiceField`? A `ModelChoiceField` lets you choose Model instances and the `queryset` determines the choices.

Comment: I didn't have them at the beginning, but the choices didn't show up so I tried to put them in to see if it works or not. And it didn't work.

Comment: By the way, can you tell why am I seeing three forms instead of two?

Comment: Remove the widget attribute, since `Select` is the default anyway. Your second form (`QuestionForm`) has the wrong queryset, I assume you want to show the `Question` instances here, not the `Topic` instances. Regarding the 3 fields (I don't see three forms, I see 3 fields), show us your template, I don't know why it's showing 3 fields.

Comment: Your `QuestionForm` has 2 fields: `questions_type` and `question_type`.

Comment: I have not noticed that, sorry, I have fixed it and now it shows only two fields, except that there are no choices.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but I think you don't want `ModelChoiceField` here. Just remove `question_type` and `topic_name` entirely from your model forms, leave only the `Meta` class. Both fields are already choice fields (not model choice fields, but normal choice fields).

Comment: I want to be able of retrieving data from the database according to topic and type of quesiton where there are two types of questions and 16 topics, through two select fields. If I remove the `ModelChoiceField` can I do that?

Comment: So your database already contains `Topic` instances and `Question` instances? Why is your form saving a new `Topic` and a new `Question` then?

Comment: I am new to Django, but this is what I have understood so far:
I build a database and then if I want to show any field on my website that retrieve data from the database, I have to use `ModelForm` and if I have understood your question correctly, I don't think my `form. py` is saving a new `Topic` and a new `Question`It is only creating a new form that contains two forms which are connected to my database.

Comment: A ModelForm is for creating/updating model instances (so you would use that to create a `Topic` or a `Question`). If you just want to let someone select an existing question and Topic, just create a `Form` with two `ModelChoiceField`s, a `topic` field  and a `question` field. No need for a `MultiModelForm`.

Comment: I am grateful for your help, allow me to summarize what I have to do,
I create a `Form` with two `ChoiceField` and include my `choices` inside of this `Form` And when whatever choice is chosen by the user, for example: `topic01` and `question_type01` will the database do the filtering by itself? And when I click on the button which I will connect to a different page using the method `GET` and `an action to a different template, the results according to the choices will show up?

Comment: No use a `ModelChoiceField` with `queryset` for `Topic` and `Question`. That's what you want, no? Choose a topic and question from the existing topics and questions in the database. Then when the form is submitted the fields will be the id of the question and id of the topic so you can do whatever you need to do with that (note that since you haven't made a model to save the choice, I can't help you with that part, I don't know what you want to do with the choice made and in your view if the form is valid you just don't do anything ( `pass`).).

Comment: The user will choose a topic and a type of questions and then will click the button to receive the questions that belong to this category on a different HTML page, just to read them that's all. No need to save the choices made by the user! And excuse me, I still cannot see the choices, it is only two fields

Comment: Ah, then the `question_type` field is indeed a `ChoiceField` with the choices of question types and then in the view, when you get the `question_type`, you can fetch the list of questions based on the question_type and render a template where you show that list. It would be easier if your HTML form just makes a GET request to a new view (a `QuestionListView`) which takes the parameters to build the list of questions.

Comment: Thank you, Sir, you have helped me a lot and I truly appropriate that.

Answer (score 0):

Your choices are not configured properly. Remove the extra () around the right side.

```
questions_type_choices = (
    (1, "Multiple Choice Questions"),
    (2, "Problem Solving Questions")
)
```

Left is stored in the database and right is displayed in form.

Comment: I have erased them but still getting nothing!